# vmware workstation and xubuntu 15.10

Tags: boot, xubuntu, vmware

I'm trying to figure out why xubuntu 15.10 desktop doesn't start up in my vmware workstation (11.1.3). I'm running xubuntu 15.04 on the same host without issues.

This is mostly a call for ideas. There's nothing wrong that I can find in:

- kernel boot logs (all standard)
- journal (only failures are for bluetooth which isn't there)
- xorg log (both default, or vmware driver)

The only unknown failure is likely unrelated (udevd failing to do `echo 180 > /dev$DEVPATH/timeout`, but doesn't report which device is it for).

Boot ends with the frozen boot splash screen. Everything seems to start up just fine in the background (according to logs on next boot). But I can't switch to the console then to verify anything else.

Answer (score 0):

It's a kernel module issue tracked in this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1548587